# add checkstyle as pre-commit git hook

Tags: java, git, hook, checkstyle

I am trying to add this: https://gist.github.com/davetron5000/37350 checkstyle code format check as pre-commit git hook.

I followed the instructions below but it doesn't work.

Steps I've tried:

> 1. Checkstyle's jar file somewhere
> 2. Checkstyle XML check file somewhere
> 3. To configure git:
>
>    - `git config --add checkstyle.jar <location of jar>`
>    - `git config --add checkstyle.checkfile <location of checkfile>`
>    - `git config --add java.command <path to java executable> [optional, defaults to assuming it's in your path]`
> 4. Put this in your .git/hooks directory as pre-commit

Maybe it doesn't work because I dont understand what `git config --add java.command <path to java executable>` means. But it says it's optional  If that's not the problem maybe I need to make the script-file an executable somehow?

ps: OS is Windows

Comment: I never used this or pre-commit hooks before but I assume `path to java executable` means the path to your `java.exe` file. It is optional because usually it is on the classpath. This `perl` program should already be an executable. I am not sure if the git utility knows how to execute it on windows or if you need another utility that knows how to.

Comment: I assumed the same. I added the path to the java.exe but it still doesnt work. Yeah since it's obviously a script i thought that it is an executable too. But it doesnt work so i wondered if its not..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay seems as i found a solution finally. I added some comments to the instructions how i made it work.

```
 1. checkstyle's jar file somewhere
 2. a checkstyle XML check file somewhere
 3. To configure git:
   * git config --add checkstyle.jar <location of jar>
   * git config --add checkstyle.checkfile <location of checkfile>
   * git config --add java.command <path to java executale> [optional
    defaults to assuming it's in your path]
```

**I checked my config (can be found in the .git directory of your git reposirtory) and it looked like this:**

```
 ...    
 [checkstyle]   
 checkfile = C:\\Users\\schuster\\Desktop\\checkstyle
 jar = C:\\Users\\schuster\\Desktop\\checkstyle    
  ...
```

**So since im Working on Windows i changed it to:**

```
...
[checkstyle]
    checkfile = C:/Users/schuster/Desktop/checkstyle/google_checks.xml
    jar = C:/Users/schuster/Desktop/checkstyle/checkstyle.jar
...
```

.

```
 4. Put this in your .git/hooks directory as pre-commit
```

**'This' is the file i linked when i stated my problem. So this file needs to be in the /hooks directory. But it has to be renamed as one of the existing samples which are already in there. Since my hook is a pre-commit hook i took the "pre-commit" filename. Next this file has to become an executable. To do that type in `chmod +x pre-commit` in the /hooks directory of your git repository. If you work with Windows do that using the Git Bash.**

### **EDIT :**

In case someone want to use this script and is wondering why it doesnt abort even if checks fail - here is how to fix it.
in line 58
         `if (&run_and_log_system ($command))`
          has to be chanted to
         `if (!&run_and_log_system ($command))`

Comment: Thank you for the fix, but by using this fix for me it just fails every time, even when no check failed.

Answer (score 2):

After configure checkstyle.jar and checkstyle.checkfile. If it does not abort on checks fail here is the fix.

At line 58

`if (&run_and_log_system ($command))`

Replace with below

```
$command .= " | grep WARN ";
if (!&run_and_log_system ($command))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've open sourced and released Commit Controls, a ZIP package that aims to natively make connecting Checkstyle in a project much easier in Javaland.

[The project homepage with documentation](https://gitlab.com/another15y/commit-controls/). Hope this project eases most use cases.